# What is the best way to put if statement in following two scenarios?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

What is the best way to put if statement in following two scenarios in R? Both answers are same and correct.

Scenario 1

```
    pow_one <- function(x, print_info = TRUE) {
      y <- x ^ 2
      if (print_info) {
        print(paste(x, "to the power two equals", y))
      }
      return(y)    
    }
```

Scenario 2

```
pow_two <- function(x, print_info = TRUE) {
  if (print_info) {
    y <- x ^ 2
    print(paste(x, "to the power two equals", y))
    return(y)
  }
}
```

Comment: `y <- x ^ 2` won't be evaluated in the second scenario if `print_info ` is `FALSE`. It really depends on whether you'll need that later on or not.

Comment: Also when you use `return(y)`, note that the function ends there. Try assign something to `y` right outside the if in the second scenario, you'll see that it won't change the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think both the functions are same but they actually are not the same. They behave the same only when `print_info` is `TRUE`.

Consider this scenario

```
pow_one(3, FALSE)
#[1] 9

pow_two(3, FALSE)
```

`pow_one` returns 9 whereas `pow_two` returns nothing because your `return` is inside the `if` block for `pow_two` which I think is not your intended behaviour.
Being "best" is subjective but IMO `pow_one` is better than `pow_two` because you need to `return` `y` irrespective if it is printed or not which is controlled by `print_info`. Moreover, it is better to have a consistent behaviour for the function. It should always return a value or never return a value.